# Search by keyword at Khan Academy

Tags: android, json

I'm working on an Android admissions app and I'm trying to do a Khan connection into my app through the API with a basic search functionality where a user can enter a keyword and the app shows a list of topics / videos / exercises that match search criteria but I'm finding it almost impossible as API doesn't provide an official "Search by keyword" method, and as any who works with Khan may  know its impossible to download the full topic tree as it ends in a 70mb file.

It's been many days of hard research and struggling my head but still wasn't able to find any documentation (if any) on how to deal with this so I thougth on asking for help. Does anyone have any idea on how to deal with this or anyone who successfully done it who can give me some hints on which direction to take?

I know you can do http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree?kind=topic (for example) but even with this filter the json results are huge (more than 10mb stream of data).

This is the way I stream the json:

```
private static String connect2Url(String urlString){

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            String temp = "";
            while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(temp);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inStream != null) {
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

And then I create the JSONObject with this result.

For the moment I'm passing "http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/%s" as url but with this you can only locate topic by id (topic slug) but cannot make a free search.

Ok, I hope anyone can help, and thanks in advance.

Edit:

As per AlphaQ suggestion I'm already investigating about GSON and Jackson and of course agree with him my parsing function is not efficient for big json streaming but anyway I'm running into two problems, the first is the json structure returned by Khan Academy is quite complex to create a class of it (I think) and the second is even if I can make a more efficient parsing the more I'm being able to filter Khan Academy json response from server is resulting in 14mb of data (the full tree is 70mb) and I guess this is still too much for a mobile app regardless on how optimized my function is, because it will have to download 14mb anyway and Khan Academy API doesn't provide a "search by keyword" method.

Give me your opinion, don't you think 14mb is still too much json data to stream for a mobile app?

This is a very little extract from the json response as an example:

```
{
    "icon_src": "",
    "twitter_url": "",
    "domain_slug": null,
    "relative_url": "/",
    "creation_date": "2016-12-14T00:46:38Z",
    "web_url": "",
    "ka_url": "https://www.khanacademy.org/",
    "translated_standalone_title": "Khan Academy",
    "has_user_authored_content_types": true,
    "translated_title": "Khan Academy",
    "gplus_url": "",
    "children": [{
            "icon_src": "",
            "twitter_url": "",
            "domain_slug": "new-and-noteworthy",
            "relative_url": "/new-and-noteworthy",
            "creation_date": "2016-09-13T20:35:19Z",
            "web_url": "",
            "ka_url": "https://www.khanacademy.org/new-and-noteworthy",
            "translated_standalone_title": "New and noteworthy",
            "has_user_authored_content_types": false,
            "translated_title": "New and noteworthy",
            "gplus_url": "",
            "children": [],
            "hide": false,
            "node_slug": "new-and-noteworthy",
            "title": "New and noteworthy",
            "child_data": [{
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1101921746"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796509722"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796388970"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "753767269"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "225139731"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "225139729"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "988721865"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "884313452"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "671536496"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "887553535"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1049279550"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796535894"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796307891"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1094139389"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796502981"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "796434657"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "871510490"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "884392300"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "x77e83a17"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "884395195"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1077533640"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1094227108"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1094119956"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1112847811"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1114711148"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1081957510"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1095856196"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1090948774"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "1013985489"
                }, {
                    "kind": "Video",
                    "id": "xca214ba1"
                }
            ],
            "user_authored_content_types_info": [],
            "id": "x29232c6b",
            "user_authored_content_types": [],
            "translated_description": "",
            "alternate_slugs": [],
            "standalone_title": "New and noteworthy",
            "logo_image_url": "",
            "in_knowledge_map": false,
            "description": "",
            "tags": [],
            "deleted": false,
            "listed_locales": [],
            "facebook_url": "",
            "render_type": "UncuratedTutorial",
            "background_image_url": "",
            "background_image_caption": "",
            "has_peer_reviewed_projects": false,
            "topic_page_url": "/new-and-noteworthy",
            "extended_slug": "new-and-noteworthy",
            "deleted_mod_time": "2013-07-13T00:03:09Z",
            "kind": "Topic",
            "curation": {},
            "slug": "new-and-noteworthy",
            "do_not_publish": false,
            "sha": "a6c251bd225b9d23e1a98f1a7fce3ccd0c8cb4fa",
            "branding_image_url": "",
            "current_revision_key": "a6c251bd225b9d23e1a98f1a7fce3ccd0c8cb4fa",
            "content_id": "x29232c6b",
            "content_kind": "Topic",
            "curriculum_key": ""
        }, {
            "icon_src": "",
            "twitter_url": "",
            "domain_slug": "math",
            "relative_url": "/math",
            "creation_date": "2017-05-08T20:15:34Z",
            "web_url": "",
            "ka_url": "https://www.khanacademy.org/math",
            "translated_standalone_title": "Math",
            "has_user_authored_content_types": false,
            "translated_title": "Math",
            "gplus_url": "",
            "children": [{
                    "icon_src": "",
                    "twitter_url": "",
                    "domain_slug": "math",
                    "relative_url": "/math/k-8-grades",
                    "creation_date": "2017-03-17T23:26:26Z",
                    "web_url": "",
                    "ka_url": "https://www.khanacademy.org/math/k-8-grades",
                    "translated_standalone_title": "K-8th grades",
                    "has_user_authored_content_types": false,
                    "translated_title": "K-8th grades",
                    "gplus_url": "",
                    "children": [],
                    "hide": false,
                    "node_slug": "k-8-grades",
                    "title": "K-8th grades",
                    "child_data": [],
                    "user_authored_content_types_info": [],
                    "id": "xf3cb93f0",
                    "user_authored_content_types": [],
                    "translated_description": "",
                    "alternate_slugs": [],
                    "standalone_title": "K-8th grades",
                    "logo_image_url": "",
                    "in_knowledge_map": false,
                    "description": "",
                    "tags": [],
                    "deleted": false,
                    "listed_locales": ["fr", "en", "pt", "de", "tr", "pl", "nb", "es"],
                    "facebook_url": "",
                    "render_type": "Subject",
                    "background_image_url": "",
                    "background_image_caption": "",
                    "has_peer_reviewed_projects": false,
                    "topic_page_url": "/math/k-8-grades",
                    "extended_slug": "math/k-8-grades",
                    "deleted_mod_time": null,
                    "kind": "Topic",
                    "curation": {
                        "modules": [{
                                "content": ["Video:xd2b0fcb4", "Article:x175a9d66", "Video:x102d9798", "Exercise:2015", "Exercise:3022"],
                                "referrer": "k_8_grades_staff_picks",
                                "kind": "ContentCarousel",
                                "title": "Staff picks"
                            }, {
                                "topic": "Topic:xd0ae8a03",
                                "kind": "SubjectIntro"
                            }
                        ],
                        "whitelist": ["Topic:xfe881476a971a3cb", "Topic:xb5feb28c", "Topic:xcef32ab6", "Topic:xef8f4cb4", "Topic:x3184e0ec", "Topic:xc7f617f2", "Topic:x5ec3eb59", "Topic:xb830458a", "Topic:x0267d782", "Topic:x6b17ba59", "Topic:x7c7044d7", "Topic:xa617314f", "Topic:x8708676b", "Topic:x7ed4701d", "Topic:x6ee1f3c2", "Topic:x0f2eb71b", "Topic:xa18e5391"],
                        "hide_community_questions": true
                    },
```

Edit 2:

I was reading all GSON documentation AlphaQ suggested me and checking out some examples but my json response is a little bit complex and I can't figure out how to define mapping class(es).

Below is the url from where I am getting the json.

Any help on how to define correctly mapping class(es) will be much appreciated.

http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree

(this is without any filtering but I could add ?kind=topic to see a full list of topics, but no more filters are allowed)

The above is a 70mb stream so I don't think it will be possible even with GSON but for me would be anough if I can do this

http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topic/math

to retrieve all math topics from this huge file.

As you see the json is too big and complex so I am not being able to figure out how to create mapping classes for this. I only need url, title and description of topics located under "children" nodes.

Comment: Try using JSON parsing libraries like `GSON` or `Jackson` for efficient parsing.

Comment: Hello AlphaQ and thanks for such a quick response, please see my edit for more comments regarding your response.

Comment: If you create a class to deserialize json into, only put the properties in there that you want to extract from the json. Gson will only fill those properties.

Comment: Good advice nbokmans and thanks, I'll start trying into this direction. Anyway let's see if anyone who was already been working with Khan knows a way to filter in server so not to stream such amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you use `GSON` or `Jackson` like I said in comments.

You can use the [hybrid streaming approach](https://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/) in Jackson to efficiently parse only the required data from the stream.

Here's an [example](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html) of using GSON.

Here's a piece of info of what the guys at Google are saying:

> Deserialized strings of over 25MB without any problems

More information [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Comment: wOw AlphaQ you are so kind!! I'll start digging into this right now and as soon as I have something functional I'll let you know. Thanks for your effort, and if I can go on with this I'll mark as resolved with this answer :)

Comment: Surely, you can go on with this. Good luck.

Comment: I was reading the documentation you suggested me AlphaQ but still cannot figure out the correct definition of the mapping class(es) so if you have a little free time Id appreciate you read my "Edit 2" and help me defining the class or classes.

Comment: You can check http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort AlphaQ, I think I'll give up with this, the fact is the response is more than 24mb of data and the "while loop" (even with GSON) takes forever to parse all content.

I'm not being able to find any other solution like a conditional parsing / mapping, I receive the 24mb stream reasonably quick but when the parsing starts you can sit and watch the full StarWars saga before it ends :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to create mapping classes for the json. If you have Visual Studio you can also copy the json and "Paste special" to create classes automatically in Visual studio.